# unexpected behaviour plotting legends with plot3d and knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, legend, rgl

I am trying to generate an html document with two 3d scatter plots using rgl using `knitr`but I am having problems when I try to add legends to both plots. Using exactly the same code (copied and pasted from one chunk to another and then changing the values to plot) the legend for the first plot is shown in the html way too large. I've generated an example script with similar data to what I am using:

````
---
title: "example"
output: html_document
---

Example script

# First plot
```{r 1st chunk, webgl=TRUE, echo = FALSE, fig.width=10, fig.height=10}
library(rgl)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
dt <- data.frame(x = runif(70, min = 1, max = 10),
                 y = runif(70, min = -10, max = 1),
                 z = runif(70, min = -20, max = -10), 
                 groups = rep(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5", "Group6", "Group7"), each = 10))
plot3d(dt$x, dt$y, dt$z, 
       xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z",
       type ="n")
grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))
legend3d("bottomright",
       c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5", "Group6", "Group7"),
       col = c(1:7),
       pch = 20,
       bg = "black",
       bty = "n",
       y.intersp = 0.8,
       cex = 1.5)
for (i in seq_along(unique(dt$groups))){
  sub <- dt[dt$groups == unique(dt$groups)[i],]
  pch3d(sub$x, sub$y, sub$z,
        col = i,
        pch = 16,
        radius = 0.2,
        add = T)}
```

This first legend is way too large, while, with the exame same code, for the next plot, the legend is normal size 

# Second plot
```{r 2nd chunk, webgl=TRUE, echo = FALSE, fig.width=10, fig.height=10}
library(rgl)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
dt <- data.frame(x = runif(150, min = 2, max = 20),
                 y = runif(150, min = -20, max = 2),
                 z = runif(150, min = -30, max = -20), 
                 groups = rep(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5", "Group6", "Group7", "Group8",
                                "Group9", "Group10", "Group11", "Group12", "Group13", "Group14", "Group15"), each = 10))
plot3d(dt$x, dt$y, dt$z, 
       xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z",
       type ="n")
grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))
legend3d("bottomright",
       c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5", "Group6", "Group7", "Group8",
         "Group9", "Group10", "Group11", "Group12", "Group13", "Group14", "Group15"),
       col = c(1:15),
       pch = 20,
       bg = "black",
       bty = "n",
       y.intersp = 0.8,
       cex = 1.5)
for (i in seq_along(unique(dt$groups))){
  sub <- dt[dt$groups == unique(dt$groups)[i],]
  pch3d(sub$x, sub$y, sub$z,
        col = i,
        pch = 16,
        radius = 0.2,
        add = T)}
```
````

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Any feedback for me?

Comment: Yes, sorry, @MikeWise. When I tried your suggestion with my data what happened is that both legends became too large. So I was trying to find out what had happened or at least to create an example that reproduced it with data more similar to my real data. I will post it as an answer soon!

Comment: So you got a different result than the one I posted?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit weird, I looked at it and noticed that the  `cex` parameter (which does mean "character expanding") in the `legend3d` call is somehow being interpreted differently in call to call. Seems like a minor bug.

However I also found you could fix it by adding an `open3d` command before each plot. Maybe that is a fix?

Code:

````
---
title: "example"
output: html_document
---

Example script

```{r 0th chunk, webgl=TRUE, echo = FALSE}
library(rgl)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```

# First plot


```{r 1st chunk, webgl=TRUE, echo = FALSE, fig.width=5, fig.height=5}
glob_cex <- 0.6

open3d()
dt <- data.frame(x = runif(70, min = 1, max = 10),
                 y = runif(70, min = -10, max = 1),
                 z = runif(70, min = -20, max = -10), 
                 groups = rep(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5", "Group6", "Group7"), each = 10))
plot3d(dt$x, dt$y, dt$z, 
       xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z",
       type ="n")
grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))
legend3d("bottomright",
       c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5", "Group6", "Group7"),
       col = c(1:7),
       pch = 20,
       bg = "black",
       bty = "n",
       y.intersp = 0.8,
       cex = 0.8 )
for (i in seq_along(unique(dt$groups))){
  sub <- dt[dt$groups == unique(dt$groups)[i],]
  pch3d(sub$x, sub$y, sub$z,
        col = i,
        pch = 16,
        radius = 0.2,
        add = T)}
```

Legends are now the same size by adding an open3d() command before each plot.

# Second plot
```{r 2nd chunk, webgl=TRUE, echo = FALSE, fig.width=5, fig.height=5}
open3d()
dt <- data.frame(x = runif(150, min = 2, max = 20),
                 y = runif(150, min = -20, max = 2),
                 z = runif(150, min = -30, max = -20), 
                 groups = rep(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5", "Group6", "Group7", "Group8",
                                "Group9", "Group10", "Group11", "Group12", "Group13", "Group14", "Group15"), each = 10))
plot3d(dt$x, dt$y, dt$z, 
       xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z",
       type ="n")
grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))
legend3d("bottomright",
       c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5", "Group6", "Group7", "Group8",
         "Group9", "Group10", "Group11", "Group12", "Group13", "Group14", "Group15"),
       col = c(1:15),
       pch = 20,
       bg = "black",
       bty = "n",
       y.intersp = 0.8,
       cex = 0.8 )
for (i in seq_along(unique(dt$groups))){
  sub <- dt[dt$groups == unique(dt$groups)[i],]
  pch3d(sub$x, sub$y, sub$z,
        col = i,
        pch = 16,
        radius = 0.2,
        add = T)}
```
````

Screen Shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you don't use `webgl=TRUE`, put an `rglwidget()` call at the bottom.  This makes the text too big, because it's scaled up from the little 256x256 rgl window; use `r3dDefaults$windowRect <- c(0,0,1000,1000)` (or similar large values) to get better sizing.

You may want to also use `options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)` at the beginning, so you don't get the windows popping up while knitting.  This has the side effect of allowing you to set the `r3dDefaults$windowRect` values to something bigger than your physical screen.

The `r3dDefaults$windowRect` and `options("rgl.useNULL")` values should only need to be set once near the top of your document, and will apply to all following plots unless you explicitly change them.